# El código es para verificar un numero primo, pero me muestra siempre que no lo es

Tags: java

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Work{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws java.io.IOException{
     int num;
     boolean isPrime;
     System.out.println("Ingrese el numero a verificar: ");
        num = (int)System.in.read();

    if (num<2) isPrime = false;
    else isPrime = true;
    
    for (int i=2;i<=num/i;i++){
        if((num % i)==0){
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(isPrime) System.out.println("Prime");
    else System.out.println("not prime");
    }
}
```

este codigo es para hallar numeros primos, pero a cualquier numero me muestra que no es primo, no se qué es lo que está mal, agradecería su ayuda

Comment: Para qué sirve esto:`i<=num/i`?

Comment: para ir verificando los divisores

Comment: El límite debería ser el número ingresado. Si en cada iteracción cumple la condición deberías tener un contador. Si ese contador hasta llegar al límite solo es 2 entonces es primo, si es mayor entonces no lo es.

Comment: Gracias, el ejercicio es de un libro de la onceava edicion "Java, the complete reference", en el libro la variable num tenía un valor asignado, pensé que funcionaría igual con cualquier número, trabajaré en entender mejor el código

Comment: El código funciona bien si asignas valores estáticos a la variable num.